# SETNX Timeout with StackExchange.Redis

Tags: redis, timeout, stackexchange.redis

Caught this random exception in the wild:

> System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type
>   'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. --->
>   System.TimeoutException: Timeout performing SETNX
>   GeoIP.[REDACTED], inst: 1, mgr: Inactive, err: never, queue: 2,
>   qu: 0, qs: 2, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 0, ar: 0, clientName:
>   PRD-VM-WEB-1, serverEndpoint:
>   Unspecified/[REDACTED].redis.cache.windows.net:6380, keyHashSlot:
>   3519, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER:
>   (Busy=1,Free=32766,Min=2,Max=32767), Local-CPU: unavailable (Please
>   take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that
>   can cause timeouts:
>   https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/tree/master/Docs/Timeouts.md)
>   at
>   StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message
>   message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server)    at
>   StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message,
>   ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server)

Using StackExchange.Redis, deployed on Azure.

From what I can tell from the [referenced cached document](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:yIIX2kIDWIIJ:https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/Timeouts.md%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk) it looks fine, perhaps the `Local-CPU` unavailable value is the problem?

Does anyone know what might of caused this to throw?

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the errors you are receiving, do you see any Timeout errors where the BUSY value is greater than the MIN for the IOCP or Worker threadpool? If so, threadpool throttling can be the cause. This often happens under bursty scenarios. This is often accompanied by high CPU, which can also cause timeouts. Threadpool throttling is explained here: https://gist.github.com/JonCole/e65411214030f0d823cb#file-threadpool-md.

Also, here are some best practices: https://gist.github.com/JonCole/925630df72be1351b21440625ff2671f#best-practices-for-azure-redis

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
SET key value EX timeout NX

SET hello world EX 100 NX
```